# Merge sort (Sort words based on frequency)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I'm writing a merge sort method that is suppose to sort words basded on frequency or on how many times they have appeared ex. Highest to lowest. For some reason my words are not sorting in the correct order, and eveything i have done seems to be logically correct and works on paper.

method:

```
public void mergeSortFreq(ArrayList<Term> toDo, int first, int mid, int last){
    int first1 = first;
    int last1 = mid;
    int first2 = mid+1;
    int last2 = last;
    int index = 0;
    ArrayList<Term> temp = new ArrayList<Term>();
    int counter = 0;

    while((first1 <= last1) && (first2 <= last2)){
        if(toDo.get(first1).getTotalFrequency() >= (toDo.get(first2).getTotalFrequency())){
            temp.add(index, toDo.get(first1));
            first1++;
            counter++;
        }
        else{
            temp.add(index, toDo.get(first2));
            first2++;
        }
        index++;
    }

    while(first1<=last1){
        temp.add(index, toDo.get(first1));
        first1++;
        index++;
    }

    while(first2<=last2){
        temp.add(index, toDo.get(first2-1));
        first2++;
        index++;
    }

    terms.clear();
    for(int i=0; i<temp.size(); i++){
        terms.add(temp.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the merge portion of mergesort, can you post your mergesort block as well? Also, in the last `while` loop, why are you using `first2 - 1` as the index instead of `first2`?

Comment: You can't merge sort this way. You should do a frequency count, merge the frequency counts, and then obtain the words in order of count.  Say you have to merge "a c" and "b c" you might come up with "a b c" but say the total of a'a are 10, the total of b's is 9 and the total of c's is 5+6=11, this means that the total of c is high even though in each list it was lower. Merge sort assumes the order of an entry cannot change due to what you merge it with.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I assumed he has unique terms already there with their frequency count calculated outside the sort method and he just sorts them now based on previously calculate freq. Then he wouldn't end up in a scenario like the one you mention

Comment: I have doubts about the -1 in `toDo.get(first2-1))`

Comment: @nem in that case, I have mis-understood the question. Not sure you would re-invent the sort algo's builtin but I assume it is home work.

Comment: I have doubts about `terms.clear();` Are you sure it is save to alter a field you don't pass in? How is this field used by the caller?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am pretty sure it is homework :)